# Camera and Viewport Not Working as Intended (LibGDX Android)

Tags: android, camera, libgdx, viewport

When I run it in the desktop, I get the correct result:

[image]

But when I run it on my Android Phone (HTC One M8 1080p screen), it displays a much larger portion of the screen. I only want it to display what you see above, but it displays that part in the bottom left corner along with some other things that I would like to appear offscreen.

[image]

The thing is, I have my camera and viewport set up exactly as in another screen, and it works in the other screen. Please help me fix this!

This is the entire MenuScreen class:

```
package com.xx4everPixelatedxx.gaterunner.screens;

import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;
import com.badlogic.gdx.InputProcessor;
import com.badlogic.gdx.Screen;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.GL20;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.OrthographicCamera;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.ParticleEffect;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.Sprite;
import com.badlogic.gdx.utils.viewport.ExtendViewport;
import com.badlogic.gdx.utils.viewport.FitViewport;
import com.badlogic.gdx.utils.viewport.Viewport;
import com.xx4everPixelatedxx.gaterunner.GateRunner;
import com.xx4everPixelatedxx.gaterunner.InputTransform;
import com.xx4everPixelatedxx.gaterunner.sprites.GameIcon;
import com.xx4everPixelatedxx.gaterunner.sprites.MenuBackground;

import java.awt.Menu;
import java.util.HashMap;

/**
 * Created by Michael Jan on 8/16/2015.
 */
public class MenuScreen implements Screen, InputProcessor {
    private GateRunner game;
    OrthographicCamera cam;
    Viewport viewport;

    private GameIcon gameIcon;
    private ParticleEffect effect;

    private MenuBackground mb, mb2;
    private Texture title_background, title, play_button, instructions_button, about_button;
    private Sprite titleSprite, playButtonSprite, instructionsButtonSprite, aboutButtonSprite;

    public MenuScreen(GateRunner game){
        this.game = game;

        Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(this);

        cam = new OrthographicCamera();
        cam.setToOrtho(false, GateRunner.WIDTH, GateRunner.HEIGHT);
        viewport = new ExtendViewport(GateRunner.WIDTH, GateRunner.HEIGHT, cam);

        title_background = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("menu/title_background.png"));
        title = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("menu/title.png"));
        play_button = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("menu/play_button.png"));
        instructions_button = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("menu/instructions_button.png"));
        about_button = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("menu/about_button.png"));

        titleSprite = new Sprite(title);
        playButtonSprite = new Sprite(play_button);
        instructionsButtonSprite = new Sprite(instructions_button);
        aboutButtonSprite = new Sprite(about_button);

        mb = new MenuBackground(1);
        mb2 = new MenuBackground(2);

        gameIcon = new GameIcon(GateRunner.WIDTH/2 - GateRunner.WIDTH/10, GateRunner.HEIGHT/10);

        effect = new ParticleEffect();
        effect.load(Gdx.files.internal("game/particles1.party"), Gdx.files.internal("game"));
        effect.start();

    }

    @Override
    public void show() {

    }

    @Override
    public void render(float delta) {
        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        cam.update();

        game.batch.begin();

        mb.update();
        mb2.update();
        mb.getSprite().setX(0);
        mb2.getSprite().setX(0);
        mb.getSprite().setY(mb.getPosition().y);
        mb2.getSprite().setY(mb2.getPosition().y);

        mb.getSprite().draw(game.batch);
        mb2.getSprite().draw(game.batch);

        titleSprite.setSize(GateRunner.WIDTH, GateRunner.WIDTH * 0.5f); //width, height
        titleSprite.setPosition(GateRunner.WIDTH / 2 - titleSprite.getWidth() / 2, GateRunner.HEIGHT / 2 * 1.35f);
        titleSprite.draw(game.batch);

        playButtonSprite.setSize(titleSprite.getWidth(), titleSprite.getWidth() * 0.133f);
        playButtonSprite.setPosition(titleSprite.getX(), titleSprite.getY() - playButtonSprite.getHeight());
        playButtonSprite.draw(game.batch);

        instructionsButtonSprite.setSize(titleSprite.getWidth(), titleSprite.getWidth() * 0.133f);
        instructionsButtonSprite.setPosition(titleSprite.getX(), titleSprite.getY() - 2 * instructionsButtonSprite.getHeight() - 10);
        instructionsButtonSprite.draw(game.batch);

        aboutButtonSprite.setSize(titleSprite.getWidth(), titleSprite.getWidth() * 0.133f);
        aboutButtonSprite.setPosition(titleSprite.getX(), titleSprite.getY() - 3 * aboutButtonSprite.getHeight() - 10 - 10);
        aboutButtonSprite.draw(game.batch);

        gameIcon.getSprite().setSize(GateRunner.WIDTH / 10, GateRunner.WIDTH / 10);
        gameIcon.getSprite().setPosition(GateRunner.WIDTH / 2 - GateRunner.WIDTH / 20, GateRunner.HEIGHT / 10 + 10);
        gameIcon.getSprite().draw(game.batch);

        effect.update(delta);
        effect.getEmitters().first().setPosition(GateRunner.WIDTH / 2 - GateRunner.WIDTH / 20 + gameIcon.getSprite().getWidth()/2, GateRunner.HEIGHT / 10 + 10); //doesnt follow gameIcon
        effect.draw(game.batch);

        game.batch.end();

        gameIcon.update(delta);
    }

    @Override
    public void resize(int width, int height) {
        viewport.update(width, height);
    }

    @Override
    public void pause() {

    }

    @Override
    public void resume() {

    }

    @Override
    public void hide() {

    }

    @Override
    public void dispose() {
        title_background.dispose();
        title.dispose();
        play_button.dispose();
        instructions_button.dispose();
        about_button.dispose();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean keyDown(int keycode) {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean keyUp(int keycode) {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean keyTyped(char character) {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean touchDown(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer, int button) {
        float pointerX = InputTransform.getCursorToModelX(GateRunner.WIDTH, screenX);
        float pointerY = InputTransform.getCursorToModelY(GateRunner.HEIGHT, screenY);

        if(playButtonSprite.getBoundingRectangle().contains(pointerX, pointerY)) //Play button
        {
            game.setScreen(new PlayScreen(game));
            dispose();
        }

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean touchUp(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer, int button) {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean touchDragged(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer) {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean mouseMoved(int screenX, int screenY) {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean scrolled(int amount) {
        return true;
    }

}
```

This is the MenuBackground class (created so the background can move):

```
package com.xx4everPixelatedxx.gaterunner.sprites;

import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.Sprite;
import com.badlogic.gdx.math.Vector3;
import com.xx4everPixelatedxx.gaterunner.GateRunner;

/**
 * Created by Michael Jan on 8/18/2015.
 */
public class MenuBackground {
    private Texture texture;
    private Sprite sprite;
    private Vector3 position;
    private Vector3 velocity;

    public MenuBackground(int i)
    {
        if(i == 1)
            position = new Vector3(0, 0, 0);
        else if(i == 2)
            position = new Vector3(0, GateRunner.HEIGHT * 2, 0);

        texture = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("menu/title_background2.png"));
        sprite = new Sprite(texture);
        sprite.setSize(GateRunner.WIDTH, GateRunner.HEIGHT * 2 + 2);

        velocity = new Vector3(0, -3, 0);
    }

    public void update()
    {
        position.add(0, velocity.y, 0);
        if(position.y - 6 <= -2 * GateRunner.HEIGHT)
        {
            position.y = GateRunner.HEIGHT * 2;
        }
    }

    public Vector3 getVelocity() {
        return velocity;
    }

    public void setVelocity(Vector3 velocity) {
        this.velocity = velocity;
    }

    public Vector3 getPosition() {
        return position;
    }

    public void setPosition(Vector3 position) {
        this.position = position;
    }

    public Sprite getSprite() {
        return sprite;
    }

    public void setSprite(Sprite sprite) {
        this.sprite = sprite;
    }

    public Texture getTexture() {
        return texture;
    }

    public void setTexture(Texture texture) {
        this.texture = texture;
    }
}
```

GateRunner.WIDTH is 480 and GateRunner.HEIGHT is 800.

Edit: added screenshot of what was happening on the android phone

Comment: A screenshot of the incorrect behaviour would be very helpful. However, you don't set a maximum viewport height, only minimum, so what you see can very well differ from device to device. Try setting a maximum viewport size as well.

Comment: I tried messing with the viewport a lot but it didn't seem to work. I tried changing to a different viewport - Fit, Stretch, they all came out with the same result.

Comment: Also, I added a screenshot of what was going on on the device now.

Comment: do you have special configuration in the the android launcher class and manifest?

Comment: also, what are the values of `GateRunner.WIDTH & HEIGHT`? if you can show us the `GateRunner` class...

Comment: @AlexandroSifuentesDíaz I actually already said what they were. It was at the very end.

Comment: I don't think this is the problem but, do you add the `android:screenOrientation="portrait"` tag in the manifest file?

Comment: Yup, I actually fixed the problem though. I just sort of deleted and recreated the title sprite. Now it works, but I don't know why.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was fixed. All I did was delete a the title sprite, and recreate it. I have no idea why this happened.